# express app server . listen all interfaces instead of localhost only

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mean

I'm very new for this stuff, and trying to make some express app

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.listen(3000, function(err) {
    if(err){
       console.log(err);
       } else {
       console.log("listen:3000");
    }
});

//something useful
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).send('ok')
});
```

When I start the server with the command:

```
node server.js
```

everything goes fine.

I see on the console

```
listen:3000
```

and when I try

```
curl http://localhost:3000
```

I see 'ok'.

When I try

```
telnet localhost
```

I see

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'
```

but when I try

```
netstat -na | grep :3000
```

I see

```
tcp  0  0 0.0.0.0:3000   0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN
```

The question is: why does it listen all interfaces instead of only localhost?

The OS is linux mint 17 without any whistles.

Comment: [The fine manual](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback) states: _"If the hostname is omitted, the server will accept connections on any IPv6 address (::) when IPv6 is available, or any IPv4 address (0.0.0.0) otherwise"_.

Comment: Thanks. it's another sign of "Explicit is better than implicit(c)", I think.

Comment: Given that accepting connections from the outside world is a basic premise for a server, listening to all interfaces (as opposed to loopback) seems to be a reasonable default to me :-)

Answer (score 158, accepted):

If you don't specify host while calling [app.listen](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.listen), server will run on all interfaces available i.e on `0.0.0.0`

You can bind the IP address using the following code

```
app.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');
```

If you want to run server in all interface use the following code

```
app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0');
```

or

```
app.listen(3000)
```

Answer (score 37):

[From the documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.listen): `app.listen(port, [hostname], [backlog], [callback])`

> Binds and listens for connections on the specified host and port. This method is identical to Node’s http.Server.listen().

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0');
```

Comment: what to give in a backlog param?

Comment: If you are getting error that there is "no such overload" when using Typescript, then ensure the first param is really number and not string. Typically we pass the first param as `process.env.PORT` which is actually string. Change that to `parseInt(process.env.PORT || '8080')`.

Answer (score 17):

document:    `app.listen([port[, host[, backlog]]][, callback])`

example:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.listen('9000','0.0.0.0',()=>{
      console.log("server is listening on 9000 port");
})
```

Note: 0.0.0.0 to be given as host in order to access from outside interface

Comment: why you missed backlog param? on my side it is giving error that **no such overload exists**